# List comprehension with partial string match

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Trying to write a function to search a requests response converted into a list of dictionaries. Each user returned will have many attributes, but I need to find users, by `display_name` based on the query passed through the main function.

Currently getting an error:

> if query in user['display_name']: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

**Function Definition**

```
def search_users(self, query, group='any'):
    # Returns list of dictionaries representing users
    users = self.get_all_users()

    for user in users:
        if query in user['display_name']:
            result_set.append(user)
```

**Main function call**

```
looker.search_users('steve')
```

Comment: Seems like your users is None, have you tried printing users before looping over it?

Comment: Yes, they print out fine. Each is a dictionary. I printed the type() as well and they came out as `str`

Comment: Hello @Joshua, and welcome to StackOverflow ! If you want the best help possible, you should give a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Specifically, without the data causing the problem, your example is incomplete.

Comment: what is `user['display_name']`? Is it a dictionary, list or just a string?

Comment: Apparently `user['display_name']` seems to be None. Provide the user sample data as well

Answer (score 1):

just change the line :

```
if query in user['display_name']:
```

to

```
if query in user.get('display_name',''):
```

the above answer will not work if the key is present and its value in `None` so i updated my answer according to @tobias_k comment -

```
if query in (user['display_name'] or ''):
```

Comment: I changed the code to your suggestion, but I'm still getting the same error:

Comment: This will probably not work. Assuming `user` is some sort of dict, `user[...]` will not return `None` if the key is not present but produce a `KeyError`. Thus the key is present but is `None`, and then `get` with default will not help. But you could try `if query in (user['display_name'] or ''):` for a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that at least one of your `display_name` values is None.

When you use the `in` keyword in that case, you're looking for something `in None`, which throws an exception.

Depending on how you wanted to handle that case, you could check if the value exists before trying to append.

```
for user in users:
        if user and user['display_name'] and query in user['display_name']:  # probably extract this check into a helper
            result_set.append(user)
```

I would extract the Boolean logic into a separate method:

```
def is_query_match(user, query):
    if user and user['d'] and query in user['d']:
        return True
    return False
```

So you could then use:

```
for user in users:
    if is_query_match(user, query):
        result_set.append(user)
```

Comment: Good quick fix @Wes, however if user itself is None, this will throw another exception

Comment: If use is None we'll get another exception, so we can also first check if `user` itself as @nandal points out

Comment: Hi @Wes, I appreciate your spontaneous help, however it still can throw an exception if user is not a dictionary or it doesn't have 'display_name' key, therefore Joshua must add some more details about the structure of user object and the list of users in order to get proper solution.